# How to solve resetting variables in a nested foreach loop in php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have string that I have converted to arrays but would like to display them in a list. How do I reset the looping to avoid repetition?

I have tried setting the variable as blank using which usually works for a single foreach statement

```
$SEAT = "1A,4A";
$NAME = "John Doe, Jane Doe";
$PHONE_NUMBER = "123456856,1235668";


$SEAT_USSD_STRING_VALUE = explode(",", $SEAT);
$NAME_USSD_STRING_VALUE = explode(",", $NAME);
$PHONE_USSD_STRING_VALUE = explode(",", $PHONE_NUMBER);

$seat_value = "";
foreach ($SEAT_USSD_STRING_VALUE as $seat_key => $seat_value) {
    $name_value = "";
    foreach ($NAME_USSD_STRING_VALUE as $name_key => $name_value) {
        $phone_number_value = "";
        foreach ($PHONE_USSD_STRING_VALUE as $phone_number_key => $phone_number_value) {
            echo "$seat_value: $name_value - $phone_number_value<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting to get

```
1A: John Doe - 12345678
4A: Jane Doe - 87654321
```

But I'm getting this

```
1A: John Doe - 12345678
1A: John Doe - 87654321
1A: Jane Doe - 12345678
1A: Jane Doe - 87654321
4A: John Doe - 12345678
4A: John Doe - 87654321
4A: Jane Doe - 12345678
4A: Jane Doe - 87654321
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, assuming that you have always equal amount of elements in your 3 arrays:

```
<?php

$SEAT = "1A,4A";
$NAME = "John Doe, Jane Doe";
$PHONE_NUMBER = "123456856,1235668";

$SEAT_USSD_STRING_VALUE = explode(",", $SEAT);
$NAME_USSD_STRING_VALUE = explode(",", $NAME);
$PHONE_USSD_STRING_VALUE = explode(",", $PHONE_NUMBER);

$seat_value = "";
foreach ($SEAT_USSD_STRING_VALUE as $seat_index => $seat_value) {
    $name_value = $NAME_USSD_STRING_VALUE[$seat_index];
    $phone_value = $PHONE_USSD_STRING_VALUE[$seat_index];
    echo "$seat_value: $name_value - $phone_value<br/>";
}
```

That case you can always refer to the item sitting on the same index in the other arrays.

This will work the following: we ar at the index 0 in the seat array loop, and then the name will be the 0 index element of the name array and the phone will be the 0 index element of the phone array.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the key (`$seat_key`) that accessible in your first `foreach`

use this `foreach` instead of all you `foreach`

```
foreach ($SEAT_USSD_STRING_VALUE as $seat_key => $seat_value) {
        echo "$seat_value: $NAME_USSD_STRING_VALUE[$seat_key] - $PHONE_USSD_STRING_VALUE[$seat_key]<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_merge`, `explode` and `array_walk` to get the desired result

```
$arr = array_merge(
    explode(',',$SEAT),
    explode(',',$NAME),
    explode(',',$PHONE_NUMBER)
);
$res = [];
array_walk($arr, function($v, $k) use (&$res){
 if($k % 2 == 0) //even
    $res['event'][] = ($k == 0) ? ($v.' : ') : ($k > 0 && $k < 4 ? $v.' - ' : $v);
else
    $res['odd'][]  =   ($k == 1) ? ($v.' : ') : ($k > 0 && $k < 4 ? $v.' - ' : 
$v);
 });
echo implode('',$res['event']).'<br/>';
echo implode('',$res['odd']).'<br/>';
```